# Shipping tax only for certain states

Tags: shipping, magento-1.6, tax

We only charge sales tax to states where we have a physical store.  Some states in the US require us to charge tax on shipping (a service, not a product) and some do not.

How can I specify which states Magento should charge tax for shipping to, and which not to charge shipping tax to?

I haven't been able to find an extension that does this, and all my searching results in Magento Go knowledgebase articles.

Does anyone else have a way to do this, or do you just charge tax on all or none of the shipping, regardless of state/region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article is for Magento 1.8, but this hasn't changed much between 1.6 and 1.8.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-tax-config-us

EDIT: Answer from below:
 So I think I understand the problem, and I think stock functionality should do this. You create two Tax Rules (tax with shipping, and tax without shipping_, and either select just "taxable goods" or select both "taxable goods" and "shipping."

Comment: That doesn't really address my question.  I have multiple tax zones and rules set up, and it works well for Products.  When it comes to shipping tax, I need to be able to exempt orders to some states, but not orders to other states.

Comment: Yeah, should have read more closely. So I think I understand the problem, and I think stock functionality should do this. You create two Tax Rules (tax with shipping, and tax without shipping_, and either select just "taxable goods" or select both "taxable goods" and "shipping."

Comment: I think I see what you're saying...I'll give it a try

Comment: That is exactly it!  I'm going to accept this answer, can you please edit your answer to include the solution?